# Jquery click function does not work on appened html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append child html of li into `div.row`. First time function is working properly but second time it does not works, however i'm using same classes for jquery selector.

I searched about it and found jquery [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), i have also tried with it and jquery `on('click','',function(){...});` but both are not working with appended function.

```js
  $( "body" ).delegate( ".list-group li a", "click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if ( $(this).parent().children('ul').length > 0 ) {
     $('.append-level').append(
      '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">'+
       '<h2>Child List Group</h2>'+
       $(this).parent().children('ul').html()+
      '</div>');
   }
  });
```

```css
.hide-child{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row append-level">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
     <h2>Parent List Group</h2>
     <ul class="list-group" id="level-one">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">First item</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Third item</a>
        <ul class="list-group hide-child">
         <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">First item</a></li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Four Third item</a>
          <ul class="list-group hide-child">
           <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">First item</a></li>
           <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
           <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Third item</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone guide me how can i implement jquery on appended html by jquery, i would like to appreciate. Thank You.

Comment: can someone please explain the reason of downvote ?

Comment: "both are working with appended function." -- so what is the problem?

Comment: #NotMyDownvote, but you did not ask a question, you requested to be walked through implementing something. This is not considered on-topic.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for letting me know about mistake, i have corrected. *Both are not working*

Comment: @HermannDöppes Sure, but if i'm facing issue i can ask question from this community. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, but you should ask *specific* questions about *specific* problems. Have you consulted your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Have you provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Have you read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @HermannDöppes My question is not general, it is in specific library and specific syntax issue. How it can i make it more specific.

Comment: @Mr.Developer “It doesn't work.” is *not* a specific problem.

Comment: #NotMyDownvote either but you should (1) provide steps of how to replicate your problem in your snippet — this is not obvious (2) explain what "it doesn't work" means and show what you've done to debug (3) run your description through a spelling/grammar checker.

Comment: @TimGrant Thanks a lot, next time i will definitely follow the instruction..

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate() function is fine (note that on() is now preferred, but does exactly the same thing as delegate() under the hood)

Your problem is your selector or html.  You original items are inside ".list-group" but your appended items aren't, so the selector won't find them.

EDIT: The above problem is casued because .html only copies the **inner** html of the ul elements.  To clone the actual ul's, wrap them and then take the .html of the wrapping element.  This seems to work:  (you could also use .clone())

```
$('.append-level').append(
                        '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">'+
                            '<h2>Child List Group</h2>'+
                            $(this).parent().children('ul').wrap('<div/>').html()+
                        '</div>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for guideline, so i have to make same function again for child list-group ?

Comment: I took another look - I see all your ul's do have list-group, but when you copy .children('ul').html() you only get the *children* of those ul's.  If you inspect your "child list groups" you will see there are li tags with no parent ul tag.  See question edit